# Extract information from ini file and add to associative array (Bash)

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I'm stucked on a bash script.
I'm having a config.ini files like this :

```
#Username
username=user

#Userpassword
userpassword=password
```

And i'm looking in a bash script to extract this information and put it in a associative array. My script looks like :

```
declare -A array
OIFS=$IFS
IFS='='
grep -vE '^(\s*$|#)' file | while read -r var1 var2 
do
    array+=([$var1]=$var2)
done

echo ${array[@]}
```

But the array seems to be empty because the commande echo ${array[@]} gives no output.

Any idea why me script don't work ? Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Why don't you just source the ini file and the call username or userpassword as variables?

Comment: Oh yeah i will do this. Didn't know that this can't be done. I just took a look on Google tried it .... and hell yeah that's my solution. Thank you very much grail.

Comment: @RaphaelVigener It's actually incredibly simple `. file`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @grail, sourcing a file as a script has the upside that it unleashes the full power of the shell language (including expanding existing variables), and the downside that it unleashes the full power of the shell language (including executing arbitrary commands though command expansion). Just something worth remembering.

Comment: @ilkkachu, of course it is the developers responsibility to know whether or not he can trust the creation of the file ;)

Answer (score 1):

Common error - "grep | while" causes the while loop to be executed in a separate shell and the variables inside the loop are not global to your shell. Use a here string instead:

```
while read -r var1 var2 
do
    array+=([$var1]=$var2)
done <<< $(grep -vE '^(\s*$|#)' file)
```

Comment: Hi, Wayne and thank you for the quick answer. Unfortunately it didn't work $var1 becomes "username user" and $var2 stays empty. With my code $var1 became "username" and $var2 became "user".

Comment: I suggest to modify Wayne‘s answer a little: `declare -A array; while IFS== read -r key value; do array["$key"]="$value"; done < <(grep -vE '^(\s*$|#)' file)`

Comment: The unquoted expansion in the here-string breaks on Bash 4.3.30: the output gets split on `IFS` characters, and then put together with _spaces_. On Bash 4.4.11 it works. But the process substitution `< <(...)` is probably better anyway as it doesn't wait for the whole string to be generated but works like a pipe.

Comment: Finally i'm sourcing the files ... that's much easier and nicer. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file can be trusted (ie the content is regulated and known), the simplest method would be to source the ini file and then directly use the variable names within the script:

```
. config.ini
```

You can either use the period (.) as above or the source builtin command